# Why socket block while in Electron

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sockets, electron

Sorry for my bad english...
i used Socket Tcp in Electron Template,But it blcoks.Is it because of a problem with the electron rendering process?
it's Electron dependences:

```
    "electron": "^2.0.4",
    "electron-builder": "^20.19.2",
    "electron-debug": "^1.5.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
```

It's Socket demo:

```
var net = require('net')
        const ctime = new Date().getTime()
        console.log(ctime)
        this.client = new net.Socket()
        this.client = net.connect({ port: 29999, host: '127.0.0.1' }, function() {
          console.log('Connected:')
          console.log(' local= %s:%s', this.localAddress, this.localPort)
          console.log(' remote= %s:%s', this._remoteAddress, this._remoteAddress)
          this.setTimeout(500)
          this.setEncoding('utf8')
          this.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log(' From Server:' + data.toString())
            this.end()
          })
          this.on('end', function() {
            console.log('Client disconnection')
          })
          this.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Socket Error:' + JSON.stringify(err))
          })
          this.on('timeout', function() {
            console.log('Socket Timed Out')
          })
          this.on('close', function() {
            console.log('Socket Closed')
          })
        })
        console.log('连接成功')
        this.client.write('aaa')
```

When i start this function,it  blocks.
[image]

When i render a table ,it connected and print some information.
[image]

And i clear this page,use codes like this.when i click test,it still block

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-button type="success" round @click="test">测试</el-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

var net = require('net')

export default {
  methods: {
    test() {

      const ctime = new Date().getTime()
      console.log(ctime)
      this.client = new net.Socket()
      this.client = net.connect({ port: 29999, host: '127.0.0.1' }, function() {
        console.log('Connected:')
        console.log(' local= %s:%s', this.localAddress, this.localPort)
        this.setTimeout(500)
        this.setEncoding('utf8')
        this.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log(' From Server:' + data.toString())
          this.end()
        })
        this.on('end', function() {
          console.log('Client disconnection')
        })
        this.on('error', function(err) {
          console.log('Socket Error:' + JSON.stringify(err))
        })
        this.on('timeout', function() {
          console.log('Socket Timed Out')
        })
        this.on('close', function() {
          console.log('Socket Closed')
        })
      })
      console.log('连接成功')
      this.client.write('aaa')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use version like this

"electron": "^20.0.0",
"electron-builder": "^20.19.2",
"electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",